# How to use 3rd party app templatetags with Jinja 2?

Tags: python, django, templates, django-templates, jinja2

I am trying Jinja2 for my Django website.

Now, since Jinja2 is not official Django templating engine and its refusing to recognise / load the template tags I was using prior to Jjinja2.

Now, even if there has to be a change in the template tags creation, then how is it possible to reflect across the 3rd party apps?

In that case it seems impossible to use Jinja2 since the system has to work as per Jinja2.

(I am also using `coffin` as an adapter for Jinja-Django).

Comment: 3rd party apps designed for django, will rely on the django template engine.

So you are right, it is not practical to expect 3rd party apps to be compatible with non-supported template engines.

Comment: In that case, I suppose everyone uses some 3rd party app for something. Even if not much but still - It makes it impossible to use Jinja2 in a practical scenario. Had `coffin` been covering all major points, but its not. So how is the industry using Jinja2 ?

Comment: @YugalJindle: Who says that the industry is using Jinja2 with django? I'm pretty sure its widely applicable beyond django. What you might be missing is that django is a framework. You can't expect a framework to have completely swappable parts from official -> 3rd party

Comment: Django's structure does not allow for swapping the template engine; since it is a core part of the system. Even if you can, using `coffin`, it is not a supported configuration; and no third-party module can be expected to support it. If you want to use jinja2, use a framework that is designed with it like `flask` or `pyramid`.

Comment: I understand.. your points since I was more of in a research mode. If that is the case, then how can you use Jinja2 with django since I am hitting performance issues on templating engine.

Comment: You need to open another question that relates your performance issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [coffin docs](https://github.com/coffin/coffin#readme) you will have to rewrite any custom django templates tags as custom Jinja2 extensions.

You could also use jinja2 macros feature to emulate the Django's template tags. The most notable difference is that for Jinja2 macros it will be necessary to provide all the context data via the template context, while in Django tags you can access data using other ways (like loading from the database or calling other Python libraries).

I've been using Jinja2 templates for a while and never had a need to create a custom template tag.

It is possible to use django templates in one app on the site and jinja2 in another app, it is not a problem, but it is not readily possible to import or extend jinja2 templates from django templates and vs versa.

Comment: How do you use `i18` with Jinja2, please provide sample code for `{% trans %}` and `{% blocktrans %}` alternatives / changes. I have almost declared `Jinja2` as un-usable since we are using 3rd party apps - whose code is not maintained by us.

Comment: {% trans %}something{% endtrans %} in Jinja2 there is only one version of trans tag. It's documented, there is also a way to do pluralization.

Comment: Great.. I will explore more of `jinja`.

Comment: Coffin's repository is gone and I'm stuck with broken `i18n` support in my `Jinja2` templates (no Flask/Django). So how do I register/hook i18n into the templates?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with coffin. Coffin supplies a way to register django-style tags to use within jinja2 templates:

```
from coffin import template
from ThrdPartyDjangoLib import djangoTagIWantToUse
register = template.Library()

register.tag('djangoTagIWantToUse', djangoTagIWantToUse)
```

Comment: It seems we can actually use `Jinja2` with Django practically. Can you elaborate a bit more? How and what it actually does ?

Comment: Not really, I don't use coffin. But if you look at their docs: https://github.com/coffin/coffin#custom-filters-and-extensions it explains how to do it.

Comment: documentation in coffin says "Coffin can automatically make your existing Django filters usable in Jinja, **but not your custom tags** - you need to rewrite those as Jinja extensions manually." you cannot auto convert Django template tags to Jinja2 template tags. Normally, with Jinja2 it is possible to avoid using template tags, as there are macros.

Comment: Then why does it give you a way to register _BOTH_ types of tags?

register.tag('foo', do_foo)       # Django version of the tag
register.tag(FooExtension)        # Jinja version of the tag

Answer (score 0):

Django's structure does not allow for swapping the template engine since it is a core part of the system. Even if you can by using `coffin`, it is not a supported configuration and no third-party module can be expected to support it. It would be same as asking third party modules to support `sqlalchemy` because you found a way to make django work with it.

If you want to use jinja2, use a framework that is designed with a pluggable template engine - or one that comes without a template engine.

The [integration page](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/integration/) lists out of the box integrations that come with Jinja2. On that page you can see that `Pyramid` is supported - and that is because *by design* pyramid allows for pluggable components.

[`Flask`](http://flask.pocoo.org/) (made by the same people behind `Jinja2`) has native support for Jinja2.

Comment: SO, you are concluding right there is no way to use `jinja2` with django unless you are ready to make even the 3rd party stuff work as per `jinja2` manually ?

Comment: +1 for a clear cut answer, I am looking for some examples where people have used `Jinja2` with Django. Since it has been talked a lot in djangocon events.

Comment: It bears mentioning here that SO is not a disucssion forum; if you have a specific problem; you need to enumerate it clearly. If you are looking for a discussion for your general wonderment or research; then this is not the place for that.

Comment: I am old enough on `stackoverflow` to know that, don't worry about that. There 2 solutions to a problem : `1` This is the solution or `2` This can-not be solved because xyz.
I very well understand stackoverflow !

Comment: It is possible to use jinja2 templates in some apps and django in others - within the same project, it is even possible to use django templates in some views and jinja in others, not that you'd normally want to do that.