# Jinja - load custom template tag set

Tags: django, django-templates, jinja2

Is there a way to load a custom tag set - or even individual custom tags?

In django templates, I was able to do this:

```
{% load custom_tag_set %}
```

Is there a way to do this in jinja?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The same mechanism exists but with a different name.

It's called [Extensions](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/extensions/#module-jinja2.ext)

Comment: So there is no clean way to use 3rd party tag sets written for native django templates?

Comment: I don't think so. Jinja is a django's template system fork if I remember well. here's another question about that same problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10949388/django-how-to-use-3rd-party-app-templatetags-with-jinja-2

Answer (score 0):

Since Django 1.8, Jinja2 is a built-in option as a template backend. In the Django docs they describe how to simulate some of Django's native template engine's context processors, filters and tags:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/templates/#django.template.backends.jinja2.Jinja2

There's also a project with extensions for Jinja2 that simulate some template tags from Django. They work the same as Django's template tags but are essentially less Jinja2-onic:

https://github.com/MoritzS/jinja2-django-tags