# Custom jinja2 tag in sphinx template

Tags: python, jinja2, python-sphinx

I'd like to implement custom navigation to my sphinx docs.
I use my custom theme based on `basic` sphinx theme. But I don't know how to create new tag for template system or use my custom sphinx plugin's directive in html templates.

Any ideas where I can plug in?

**Update**

As I can see in sphinx sources, jinja2 environment constructed in <s>`websupport`</s> `jinja2glue` module. Though I can't understand the way it can be reconfigured besides monkey-patching.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found a good way to do this. Sphinx's configuration parameter `template_bridge` allows to control over `TemplateBribge` object - which is responsible for themes rendering.

Standard `sphinx.jinja2glue.TemplateBridge` constructs `environment` attribute in `init` method *(it's not a constructor, unfortunate name for method)* - which is jinja2's environment itself used for templates rendering. So just subclass `TemplateBridge` and override `init` method.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/extensions/#module-jinja2.ext , extensions are used for adding custom tags in Jinja

Also have a look at [Django : How to use 3rd party app templatetags with Jinja 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10949388/django-how-to-use-3rd-party-app-templatetags-with-jinja-2)

Comment: I understand how jinja2 extensions can be created. I just see no place in sphinx project to plug it.